# Java - How to build an exe using Excelsior JET?

Tags: java, exe

I'm a beginner programmer in Java, and I'd like to build an exe from my jar. The jar I want to use contains 4 classes, and I compiled it using Eclipse.

Now, when I try to paste it in [Excelsior JET](http://www.excelsiorjet.com/), I get the following error message: "Main Class is not specified." Is there something I should write in my Manifest file? If yes, what would that be?

Comment: Why use Java if you want an exe?

Comment: @Stultuske For instance, if you know Java and *need* to make an EXE, using a Java tool from [this list](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/best-jar-to-exe-conversion-tools-free-commercial.html) is more effective than teaching yourself C++ or whatever you think is the best tool for making EXEs.

Comment: @DmitryLeskov: it has nothing to do with 'what the best tool is to create exe's', it has to with: what is an exe. One of the greater benefits of using Java, is that it's platform independent. One of the disadvantages is: it's limited in it's access to the OS and System. Unlike C and C++, for instance. Basically: creating an exe (which is a Windows native executable) of a Java application means: giving up some of the greater advantages of using Java, while still suffering from the disadvantages.

Comment: In my entire life, I only encountered 1 single time we needed it to be an exe. it's the kind of application beginners don't stumble upon.

Comment: @Stultuske Your Java source does not become less portable if you package the resulting class files as a native binary, whether a real thing or just a wrapper. After all, some Java apps ship as platform-dependent installers with private JREs inside. How this is different? You can make an iOS binary from C# using Xamarin. Does that constitute giving up on any of the benefits of using C#?

Comment: I'll take a .jar, you take the .exe, let's see who can make it run on the most platforms.

Comment: Programs are for users, not platforms. Give a jar to a thousand random Windows users, let's see how many of them can run it. (Bonus challenge: run a jar on iOS w/o turning it into a native binary.)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by setting `Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass` in your JAR file manifest.

Refer to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) here. In eclipse, you can do it [this way](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm).